# Changing the target path of a Views more link

Tags: views

Drupal 6, Views 2.

I would like the "View" link to point somewhere completely different than it normally does.

I've implemented `hook_views_pre_render()` and dug around in the `$view` object, but I can't seem to find the path in there.

How can I change the "View" link?

Comment: Are you talking about the links that's possibly created  on the view (like pagers) or the url that the user uses to get the view displayed in the first place?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which links you mean either ;) Views has a "Create more link" option, which generates a link to view "More content" of the current type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all else fails, just edit the views template.  Go into the views theming information and select the template and edit the more link for it.  It would be named along the lines of `views-view--MYVIEWNAME--MYVIEWDISPLAYNAME.tpl.php` and inside you can edit the more link area in the template.  (There is also a `more` template you can modify but I've not done it that way before)

```
<div class = "more-link">' .
l(
  t('See more'),
  'internal/path/' . $view->args[0],
  array('options' => array('HTML' => TRUE))
) .
'</div>';
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to manipulate already rendered HTML? That gives me an idea though...

Comment: nope, the template is what generates the html

Comment: The more link is already rendered at that point, and simply available as a $more variable, which contains HTML. Or am I being slow now? Copied from a template: <?php if ($more): print $more; endif; ?>. I found a more-link.tpl.php as well, but there doesn't appear to be a $view in there, so I can't control it without making it theme global.

Comment: Instead of `<?php if ($more): print $more; endif; ?>` put in  `<?php print l('GO HERE','http://www.foo.com'); ?>` or whatever you want or grab any values you want out of `$row` etc.

Comment: So, thus far, I was just being stupid >_<. However, $rows, has _also_ already been rendered at this stage, meaning I would be forced to reverse lookup the term-id I'm looking for from a path-auto alias.

Comment: Ah....views always has a `$view` variable available in all of the templates, and `$view->result` is an array of the row results, so, if you put a `foreach($view->result as $r => $row) {
  drupal_set_message('<pre>' . $r . ': ' . print_r($row,true) . '</pre>');
}` in the top of your template, you could see all the information you are looking for.

Comment: Somewhat obviously, if the information in question is the same in each row, just look at `$view->result[0]` :)

Comment: I actually _did_ think about this, but saw that $view wasn't in the list of variables. Before I posted back about _that_ though, I actually _tried_ using $view, and it worked as you suggested. I updated your question with an example. Would it be appropriate to flag the answer for a moderator, to remove this now superfluous discussion? I'm most grateful for your help.

Comment: your example is just one of many ways to use the $view variable so the discussion "shows the math" but all good either way.  glad I could help out!

Answer (score 6):

I used this method (views 3.x):

```
 <?php
 // get the $view object somehow and alter the display_handler options
 // see views_plugin_display.inc ~ render_more_link() method
 $view->display_handler->set_option('link_display', 'custom_url');
 $view->display_handler->set_option('link_url', 'node/!1/somewhere');
```

Comment: I used this in hook_views_pre_render().

Comment: Yes, it can be used anywhere a $view is available, eg from `views_get_view("view_name")`

Answer (score 1):

Although views templates are very powerful, if all you need is a link, you could just put one in the footer field and use the same css class views does for read more links.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the footer field, as I need tokens, which is not supported in Views 2.

Answer (score 1):

Just building on what was mentioned above (I didn't feel comfortable just editing the original answer).

For Views 3: You can do the following....

- Add a More link with custom text
- Create your views tpl file using hte 'Display' style
- Within the views tpl file change the More code to:

  ```
  if ($more): 
      print str_replace('/front', '/latest-news', $more);
  endif;
  ```

*Note:* You will need to add the proper php code around each line (I couldn't figure out how to do that in the editor :(